# Why does a piece of code that works on its own not work in parallel in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, doparallel, parallel-foreach

I wrote a piece of code (appended below) that works fine when I run it in serial, but when I use the foreach and doparallel libraries in R, I get an error code that reads: " task 1 failed - "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Everything inside the for each loop works on its own, and on a smaller batch, I can run it serially and it works.

```
ListOfColumns <- colnames(tempdata)
  foreach(i = 1:nSubsets,
    .export = ls(globalenv())) %dopar% {
      DoubleTempData <- get(paste0("Subset", i))
      DoubleTempData <- subset(DoubleTempData, select = -c(subset))
      RowCounter <- 2
      ColumnFigurer <- 2
      LastCATEGORYIndicator <- "THERE IS NO CATEGORY, ONLY ZUUL"
      while (RowCounter <= nrow(DoubleTempData)) {
        print(paste("Checking row ", RowCounter))
        RowChecker <- max(1, RowCounter - 5)
        while (RowChecker < RowCounter) {
          print(paste("Checking row",
                      RowCounter,
                      "against row",
                      RowChecker))
          if (DoubleTempData$CATEGORY[RowChecker] == DoubleTempData$CATEGORY[RowCounter])
          {
            print("The rows match!")
            while (ColumnFigurer > 0) {
              if (DoubleTempData$CATEGORY[RowCounter] != LastCATEGORYIndicator) {
                ColumnFigurer <- 2
              }
              print(paste ("Checking Iteration", ColumnFigurer))
              if (ColumnFigurer * length(ListOfColumns) <= length(colnames(DoubleTempData)))
              {
                print(paste("Iteration", ColumnFigurer, " exists"))
                CellChecker <-
                  ((ColumnFigurer - 1) * length(ListOfColumns) + 1)
                if (is.na(DoubleTempData[[RowChecker, CellChecker]])) {
                  print(paste("Current value is NA. Writing in new value."))
                  ColumnCounter <- 1
                  while (ColumnCounter <= length(ListOfColumns)) {
                    DoubleTempData[[RowChecker, (ColumnFigurer - 1) * length(ListOfColumns) +
                                      ColumnCounter]] <-
                      DoubleTempData[[RowCounter, ColumnCounter]]
                    ColumnCounter <- ColumnCounter + 1
                  }
                  DoubleTempData <- DoubleTempData[-RowCounter]
                  LastCATEGORYIndicator <-
                    DoubleTempData$CATEGORY[RowChecker]
                  RowCounter <- max(2, RowCounter - 1)
                  ColumnFigurer <- ColumnFigurer + 1
                  break
                }
                else
                {
                  print(paste(
                    "Current value is not NA, increasing iteration count."
                  ))
                  ColumnFigurer <- ColumnFigurer + 1
                  }
              }
              if (ColumnFigurer * length(ListOfColumns) > length(colnames(DoubleTempData)))
              {
                print(paste(
                  "Iteration ",
                  ColumnFigurer,
                  "does not exist, adding iteration."
                ))
                ColumnAdder <- 1
                while (ColumnAdder <= length(ListOfColumns)) {
                  NewColumnName <-
                    paste0(ListOfColumns[ColumnAdder], "_", ColumnFigurer)
                  DoubleTempData[, NewColumnName] <- NA
                  ColumnAdder <- ColumnAdder + 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
          RowChecker <- RowChecker + 1
        }
        RowCounter <- RowCounter + 1
      }
      assign(paste0("Subset", i), DoubleTempData)
    }
```

For example, here is a sample of a randomly generated Subset1 that I ran, with about 70 observations and 7 columns (one of which gets dropped by the program as intended):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlytj.png

It then outputs a dataset with 9 observations, and 60 columns:
[image]

Comment: I suggest you add `message` (or `cat` or something) statements before every `if` and `while` block in your code, and capture the output. At some point, you should find that something is `NA`, and you'll know where to focus your efforts. (BTW: your code is incomplete, perhaps missing just a right-paren at the end.)

Comment: The parallel workers don't have access to the global environment. That means, e.g., you can't assign into it.

Comment: Roland, I thought that was what the ".export = ls(globalenv())" was for.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I have added some examples.